# java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points with KeyboardType.Decimal

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, android-compose-textfield

I'm using `KeyboardType.Decimal` for the keyboard type in the  `keyboardOptions` entry shown below for an `OutlinedTextField`, but it's allowing multiple decimals in the typed number. And doing any conversions on such an input like `"2.5.8".toDouble()` throws a `multiple points` exception shown below. How can I ensure that only one decimal point is allowed and any subsequent decimal key presses don't do anything?

**Composable**

```
CustomOutlinedTextField(
    fieldModifier = Modifier
        .width(100.dp)
        .onFocusChanged {
            if (!it.isFocused) {
                if (mainViewModel.shoppingListItemState.value.quantity == "" || mainViewModel.shoppingListItemState.value.quantity == "0") {
                    mainViewModel.setStateValue(
                        ITEM_QUANTITY_STR,
                        "1"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        .onPreviewKeyEvent {
            if (it.key == Key.Tab && it.nativeKeyEvent.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Right)
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
    label = ITEM_QUANTITY_STR,
    inputVal = mainViewModel.shoppingListItemState.value.quantity,
    isSingleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
        capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
        autoCorrect = false,
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Next
    ),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Right) }
    )
) { value ->
    mainViewModel.setStateValue(ITEM_QUANTITY_STR, value)
}
```

**Exception**

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
```

Comment: Check inside `onValueChanged` block if the text already have a decimal point or not. If already there is a period, just ignore it and submit the value to state observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the number of `decimalSeparator` in the `onValueChange` of your `TextField` and allow only one.
It is advisable to get the `decimalSeparator` instead of comparing with `.` since it might change based on device Locale.
Below is a sample implementation of a `TextField` which checks and allows only one `decimalSeparator`.

```kotlin
val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()) as DecimalFormat
val decimalSeparator = decimalFormat.decimalFormatSymbols.decimalSeparator

var text by remember { mutableStateOf("123") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal
    ),
    onValueChange = { value ->
        val counter = value.count { it == decimalSeparator }
        if (counter <= 1) { text = value }}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex in the `onValueChange` to restrict the allowed character to a decimal number.

Something like:

```
val pattern = remember { Regex("^\\d*\\.?\\d*\$") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty() || it.matches(pattern)) {
            text = it
        }
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal),
)
```

[image]